# How to get one record per section when using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I work on an iOS app that uses Core Data and I want to display an entity using UITableView.

For that I'm using a NSFetchedResultsController. 
The thing I am trying to achieve is to display each record in it's section. Basically I want 1 row per section.

The methods that I am struggling with are :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

because I want to have this piece of code when computing the numberOfSectionsInTableView:

```
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

and I want to have `return 1` when computing the numberOfRowsInSection (and obviously I can't pass `indexPath.section`to `numberOfSectionsInTableView`).
What is the approach in this problem/situation? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well,

Obviously, you will have as much section as you have object :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return self.fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects.count;
}
```

then, you will only have one row / section since this is what you want

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 1;
}
```

then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath use the indexPath.section as a rowIndex and the indexPath.row as the sectionIndex.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath * correctedIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.section inSection:0];

    id myItem =  [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath: correctedIP];
/* ... */

}
```

Comment: The corrected IP shouldn't swap row and section. It should use `section` for the row and `0` for the section. Yes it might always be zero but better to do it explicitly.

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you very much for the quick and correct response, both @Fogmeister and Florian Burel. You are awesome.